# Appending link element within list element dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

With using jquery I need to create a  element to be added inside a `<li>` which has its own content. Final result should be like below

```
<li> Hello <a> user! </a> Welcome! </li>
```

So far I have tried out below.

```
var list = $('<li></li>');
     var link = $('<a></a>');
      link.innerHTML = "user!";
list.append(link);
```

But this will give an output like below.

```
<li> <a> user! </a> </li>
```

How can I include 'hello' and 'welcome' on the either side of `<a>` ?

Comment: Despite of high reputation, people still don't know how to post! `:(` Your question makes no sense. What you wanna achieve?

Comment: `$('<li> Hello <a> user! </a> Welcome! </li>')` or `$('<li/>',{html : ' Hello <a> user! </a> Welcome! '})`

Comment: I meant the final output should be where the link element is added inside a list element. It's evident that it can be done with a .append. But here I need it to be added in between the content of the list item. So I was just showing how the result should look like with (<li> Hello <a> user! </a> Welcome! </li>)

Comment: @PranavCBalan *When people says, Paraveen or Paranav, that fire in us...*

Comment: Thanks Pranav. I was looking if this was possible with having the <a> tag separately as an element. Need it for another purpose.

Comment: @PraveenKumar : most of the time they were says like that :D

Comment: @user2894296 : then do => `$('<li/>',{html : [document.createTextNode(' Hello') ,$('<a> user! </a>'), document.createTextNode('Welcome! ')]})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```js
console.log(
  $('<li/>', {
    html: [
      document.createTextNode(' Hello'),
      $('<a> user! </a>'),
      document.createTextNode('Welcome! ')
    ]
  })[0].outerHTML
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```